# Oracle sql query to find the data as of last 15 minutes

Tags: sql, oracle, bi-publisher

I have a query that picks up the last_update_date in the format -

```
  person_number    last_update_date                                  location
     10             2021-06-10T16:02:50.222+00:00                     Peru
     11             2021-06-10T16:03:50.222+00:00                     Argentine
```

query-

```
select person_number,
last_update_Date,
location
```

I want to add a where clause in this so that the query picks up only the last 15 minutes chanegs in the last_update_date. i.e. all teh records that has the timestamp for last 15 minutes.

is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if date column is between sysdate(this is current time) and sysdate- (1/1440*15)(this is current time -15 minutes)

```
select person_number,
last_update_Date,
location,
sysdate,
sysdate - (1/1440*15) 
from tab1
where last_update_date between sysdate - (1/1440*15) and sysdate
```

[Here is a demo made at 2022-06-10 20:35:00](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bd2d9e6ad323de32de5763f8ceeab3a9)

Comment: Hi @SSA_Tech124, does this answers your question ?

Answer (score 0):

Use an `INTERVAL`:

```sql
SELECT person_number,
       last_update_Date,
       location
FROM   table_name
WHERE  last_update_date BETWEEN SYSDATE - INTERVAL '15' MINUTE
                            AND SYSDATE
```